# How to solve web scraping error in R when accessing a web page that requires username and password?

Tags: r

I am trying to access a table that shows the level of adoption of microsoft licenses, I developed a script but when I ran it the answer gave me an error.

Does anybody know how I can fix it?

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

handle <- handle("https://login.microsoftonline.com/") 
path   <- "common/login"

login <- list(
  amember_login = "username"
  ,amember_pass  = "password*"
  ,amember_redirect_url = 
    "https://partner.microsoft.com/es-es/dashboard/analytics/usageanalytics"
)

response <- POST(handle = handle, path = path, body = login)

readHTMLTable(content(response))
```

the error is the following

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"xml_document"’
```